# How does someone move space?

Tags: energy, spacetime, space-expansion, warp-drives

I've heard that we've known components of the universe appear to be flying apart faster than $c$, and that this can happen because the space containing these materials are also moving apart.

How does someone move space? How efficiently can it be done?

I would like to get on a rocket and then move the space very close to Sedna and see what it looks like. What are the physical barriers to doing that?

Comment: Are you thinking of something like this?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive

Comment: @AlfredCentauri: yes, that is pretty much what I was wondering. Can you put that as an answer so I can check it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, the space is not actually **moving**, but **expanding**; Which means that objects **in** this space are "moving apart".

Now, "moving apart" has not much to do with the physical term of moving.

Essentially, one does not move space because that makes no sense; Not because it is impossible.

(Or, more poetically: It is not even impossible to move space.)